# What does the e equate to in the sigmoid function?

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence

How do I know what the letter e equals in the sigmoid function?

1/(1+e^activationFunction)

In javascript is it just

return 1/(1+Math.E^(x));
Or is E not euleger's number?

```
console.log(1/(1+Math.exp(0))); // .5
console.log(1/(1+2.718281828459045^(0))); // 0.3333333333333333
```

Math.exp definitely works but when I do Math.exp(1) I get 2.718281828459045. When I plug that in and raise it to a power, it breaks?

**Solution** by @blgt

```
console.log(1/(1+Math.pow(2.718281828459045, 1))); // 0.2689414213699951 It works!
```

Comment: Yes, it is Euler's number. Though you can also use `Math.exp()`

Comment: Doesn't work if I plug in the number. I'll edit my original question. Thank you!

Comment: It's working as expected; except `^` is the bitwise xor operator. Use `Math.pow()` for the power funciton.

Comment: @blgt console.log(1/(1+Math.pow(2.718281828459045, 1))); // 0.2689414213699951

Comment: blgt if you want to copy and paste what I wrote, I will gladly upvote and accept your solution now

Comment: There's already an answer saying the same thing just tick it : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*e* is eulers number. In javascript, use Math.exp(*x*) to obtain it:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/exp

To get 1/(1+e^x) in javascript, use

```
var y = 1 / (1 + Math.exp(x));  // y = 1/(1+e^x)
```

The ^ symbol is the XOR operator, not to be confused with the mathematical exponent operator. To get the exponent *n* of a base number *b*, use

```
Math.pow(b,n);
```

If you insist on "extracting" the value of *e* before using it, use this:

```
var e = Math.exp(1);
var y = Math.pow(e,x); // = e^x
```

Comment: Please look at my re-written question, sir or ma'am.

Comment: Math.exp(1) = 2.718281828459045. Yet when I plug that number in for e, it breaks the function.

Comment: Thanks, already figured that part out. Currently separating the bottom of the fraction out over here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1741989/how-to-divide-the-fraction-1-11

Comment: Whoops typo in my comment, fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

e= 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! +.... up to infinity terms
= the value is an irrational number
the value of e approximates 2.71828....
For calculation purpose, one may take as many digits after decimal as required for accuracy.

Comment: author was not asking for formula